# Line regulation of zener diode with jfet

Tags: power-supply, zener, jfet

How am I able to calculate line regulation (S=dUout/dUin) for zener diode with current provided by JFET with zero gate - source voltage? Schematic below

[image: schematic]

Lets say it's typical BF256B as JFET and BZX84-B5V1 as Zener diode.
Is it calculable or just equal 0?

Comment: This circuit would depend on what your Vcc and other terminal/node was connected to. The JFET is a current source. The diode sill passes some current (they always do, *how much current* is the question). How do you know the voltage is zero at the gate? None of your nodes are labeled with a votlage

Answer (score 1):

The FET is being used as a constant current source. 
Reference to the [datasheet](http://akizukidenshi.com/download/ds/fairchild/BF256B.pdf) shows the current could be anywhere from 6-13 mA.

Your should read this Siliconix/Vishay [app note](http://www.vishay.com/docs/70596/70596.pdf) to understand the elements around setting up a CC source with a JFET. Providing the FET is in saturation (V(DSS) is high enough) you can assume that the conductance is approaching zero.

Your deltaVout/DeltaVin will approach zero providing the FET is in saturation.

Answer (score 1):

A JFET conducts when it's gate-source voltage is zero and gradually stops conducting when you take the gate voltage lower than the source voltage. As such, in the data sheet it tells you this: -

[image]

If you have a data sheet for the zener you can estimate what variation in zener voltage you can get from the current range listed above.

Or, if you have a simulation tool it might provide better models to work with than just making hand calculations.

Comment: The datasheet appears to have a typo; `Vgs=15V, Vgs=0V` should probably read `Vds=15V, Vgs=0V`. How the current varies with other values of Vds is not specified thare...

Comment: @BrianDrummond well spotted.